# How can I fix this key error when trying to connect to mySQL database?

Tags: python, mysql, psycopg2

I am currently creating a Graphical User Interface for a school project on Jupyter Notebook, I have been trying to connect to MySQL so that I can create a database for my gui but it keeps execting the error "KeyError: 'db_host'" but I am not understanding why, this is my first time making a database so I am thinking it is just a simple rookie mistake but Im not sure.

Here is the code:

```
import os
import psycopg2 as ps
import pandas as pd

conn = ps.connect(
    host=os.environ["db_host"],
    port=os.environ["db_port"],
    dbname=os.environ["db_name"],
    user=os.environ["db_user"],
    password=os.environ["db_password"])
```

I have tried changing the `db_host` and everything but it kept producing the same error, so at this point I am very confused.

here is the full error code:

```
 import psycopg2 as ps
      3 import pandas as pd
      5 conn = ps.connect(
----> 6     host=os.environ["db_host"],
      7     port=os.environ["db_port"],
      8     dbname=os.environ["db_name"],
      9     user=os.environ["db_user"],
     10     password=os.environ["db_password"])ype here
```

Comment: Do you know what `os.environ` does? Have you set an evironment variable "db_host" in the environment? And this has nothing to do with the database. A simple `print(os.environ["db_host"])` would give the same error.

Comment: import psycopg2 as ps is used to connect to postgresql not mysql
you probably need 
import mysql.connector

Comment: I don't know what os.environ does, I am still new to this.

Comment: `os.environ` is a python module to contain the environment variable of configuration files. in this case. the `KeyError: db_host` error message that you get because probably you haven't set the key and value of `db_host` in your environment